# custom keyboardの中でMPMusicPlayerControllerを読み込む

Tags: swift, ios, swift3, ios-app-extension

Swift3でカスタムキーボードを作り、ボタンを押したときに
`MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer().nowPlayingItem`で引き出した曲のタイトル（`.title`）や歌詞（`.lyrics`）などを挿入したいと思っているのですが、

通常のアプリのように
`MediaPlayer`をインポートし、`keyboardViewController`内に`MPMusicPlayerController`のインスタンスを宣言し、`nowPlayingItemDidChange`の通知を受けたときにselectorで指定したメソッドを呼び出し、曲の情報を取得するようにコードは書いてあります。

カスタムキーボードのApp ExtensionにはMediaPlayerは**対応していない**のでしょうか？
それとも、何か**特別な処理**が必要になるのでしょうか？

あるいは、カスタムキーボードの**ホストアプリ上で情報を取得し、その情報をキーボードに受け渡す**という動作や、いっそカスタムキーボードではなく、ただの**シングルビューアプリとUIButtonとUITextView**で実装できればそれでもいいのですが・・・

Answer (score 0):

カスタムキーボードのExtensionについては試したことがないので良くわかりませんが、カスタムキーボードでなくても良い（自アプリ内のみで利用できればよい）のなら拙作のアプリ [SongsInfo](https://itunes.apple.com/jp/app/songsinfo/id428766423?mt=8) のツイート機能で似たようなことを行っています。

このアプリでは、UITextView の inputView に UITableView を設定することでキーボードの代わりに曲のメタ情報を挿入可能にしています。

[image: SongsInfoのツイート機能]

あと、曲の情報を参照するなら、Info.plist に [Privacy - Media Library Usage Description](https://qiita.com/motoshima1150/items/884d57d0b1ea14403cdc) を含めるのをお忘れなく。